# How to increase number of results returned by QGIS locator bar

Tags: qgis-3

In QGIS 3.x, the [Locator bar](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_gui.html#locator-bar) can be used to perform various kinds of search. However, it only returns up to 6 results for searching 'Features in All layers'. How to force it to return all possible results?

Comment: If you want to compile QGIS yourself, you could edit this from the [source code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/6d34089a82c50bb454b0fccf23f78fa18f7befc5/src/app/locator/qgsinbuiltlocatorfilters.h#L155). Otherwise, I'm not sure it is possible to edit the results yet.